# Preventing duplicate values in an ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, duplicates, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I'm listing a load of sports fixtures via ng-repeat, but I only want to show the `date` value on its first occurrence. Additionally, I want to contain this date value inside a div, with an `<hr>` tag.

I'm guessing I should apply an `ng-if` to the tag, and set the corresponding function to evaluate to true if it the first occurrence of that value in the `getFixtures` array. I'm not quite sure how to do this though, or if it is indeed possible.

### HTML

```
<div class="fixture" ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures">

    <div ng-if="doNotDuplicate()">  
       <h4>{{fixture.formatted_date}}</h4>
       <hr>
    </div>

    <div layout="row" style="max-width: 450px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="fixtureteam" flex="40" style="text-align: right;">
            <h2>{{fixture.localteam_name | fixturesAbbreviate}}<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{fixture.localteam_id}} md-whiteframe-1dp" style="margin: 0 0 0 8px;"></span></h2>
        </div>

        <div flex="20" layout-align="center center" style="text-align: center;"><h2>{{fixture.time}}</h2></div>

        <div class="fixtureteam" flex="40" style="text-align: left;">
            <h2><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{fixture.visitorteam_id}} md-whiteframe-1dp" md-whiteframe="1dp" style="margin: 0 8px 0 0;"></span>{{fixture.visitorteam_name | fixturesAbbreviate}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

### VIEW (desired outcome)

### 1st June

---

Fixture A
Fixture B
Fixture C

### 2nd June

---

Fixture D
Fixture E

### 4th June

---

Fixture F
Fixture G

---

Any help/suggestions will be massively appreciated.

Comment: Why just not to group your items by date?

Comment: Do you mean write a separate ng-repeat for every date value, and filter it by that value?

Comment: Yes.First `ng-repeat` by dates and the second one by fixtures (per date).

Comment: Could you give me a rough idea of the syntax for that? I've never done nested ng-repeats...

Comment: I put the answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<div class="fixture" ng-repeat="item in getFixtures | groupByDate">
    <div>  
       <h4>{{item.date}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="fixture in item.fixtures">
        ...
        // display fixture info
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

where `groupByDate` is custom filter (as an option) to group fixtures by date.

**EDIT:**

You can create your own filter or you can try to use already existed third-party filter from [angular-filter module](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

There you can find the [groupBy filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) and use it like:

**JS**

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- result:
  Group name: alpha
    * player: Gene
  Group name: beta
    * player: George
    * player: Paula
  Group name: gamma
    * player: Steve
    * player: Scruath
```

---

Hope it will help.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to write the filter! Would it have to be in a filter module?

Comment: Thanks! That filter is amazing, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a filter and pass getFixtures through it. The filter could iterate over the list adding a flag to the required items (by checking index===0 or current date !== previous date). I am assuming that the list is already sorted by date.

If you don't want to "pollute" the original then copy each element and add to a new array but this would obviously have a performance hit which may or may not be significant.